# How to Create and Utilize Jenkins Job Templates with Jenkins Configuration as Code (JCasC)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jcasc

I've created a Jenkins Job template using a YAML file, which primarily consists of parameters. Now, I'm looking for guidance on how to use this job template to parameterize other pipeline jobs within Jenkins Configuration as Code.

Here are some specific questions I have:

1. What is the recommended approach for defining job templates with parameters in JCasC?
2. How can I reference and utilize the parameters defined in the job template within other pipeline jobs?
3. Are there any configuration examples or best practices for incorporating job templates with parameters into JCasC configurations?

Any insights, examples, or resources that demonstrate the implementation of job templates with parameters in a JCasC-managed Jenkins environment would be greatly appreciated.